# Typescript: Not able to update member variable inside forEach block

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push values dynamically to my data member inside the constructor, 
but inside the forEach block, I'm not able to access that member.

Here **AppComponentClass**

```js
export class AvailableRidersComponent {
  public availableDrones: Pickdrone[];
  constructor() {
    const db = firebase.database();
    const availableRidersRef = db.ref('/riders/active_riders/available/');
    availableRidersRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        const riderProfileRef = db.ref('/riders/Pickdrones/' + childSnapshot.key);
        riderProfileRef.on('value', dataSnap => {
          const riderProfile = {
            name: dataSnap.val().name,
            id: dataSnap.key,
            contact: dataSnap.val().contact,
            email: dataSnap.val().email
          };
          console.log(riderProfile); //Prints values properly
          this.availableDrones.push(riderProfile); //ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'availableDrones' of undefined
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and here us my **Pickdrone class**

```
export class Pickdrone {
public name: string;
public id: string;
public contact: string;
public email: string;
// vehicleType: string;

constructor(name: string, id: string, contact: string, email: string){
    this.name = name;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

Comment: `this` in a callback won't be your class anymore without binding, create a local variable that holds the `this` context before firing the request to the database, so that you can use the local variable inside your callback

Comment: Alternatively, to creating a local variable, you can use arrow functions. Have a look at the chapter `this and arrow functions` over at [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)

Comment: @Icepickle thank you, That was the problem. but now it's saying that the push is undefined. can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize your `availableDrones` array , like this for example:

```
public availableDrones: Pickdrone[] = {};
```

and also for better code, make the constant `riderProfile` of type `Pickdrone`
as:

```
      const riderProfile: Pickdrone = {
        name: dataSnap.val().name,
        id: dataSnap.key,
        contact: dataSnap.val().contact,
        email: dataSnap.val().email
      };
```

so that the compiler can check if you input the correct type for each property.